# How to pass input from one textarea to another's output?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning JS again and I've run into this problem while making an app.

I can't pass input from one textarea to second textarea which is output. I want to make the text uppercase on output. I tried to modify code from [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_touppercase) but I want to make it without button so it looks cleaner.

What I want to achieve:

1. User writes something in input
2. His text is copied to output and changed to uppercase letters

HTML

```
    <h3>INPUT</h3>
    <textarea id="inputText" placeholder="input" cols="70" rows="10" wrap="on"></textarea>
    <h3>OUTPUT</h3>
    <textarea id="outputText" placeholder="output" cols="70" rows="10" wrap="on" readonly></textarea>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("inputText") = str;
var res = str.toUpperCase();
document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML = res;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what part of your JavaScript that is, but `str` is not defined. Here's a working version.

```js
const uppercaseEl = document.getElementById('outputText')
function update(el) {
    uppercaseEl.value = el.value.toUpperCase()
}
```

```html
<h3>INPUT</h3>
<textarea id="inputText" oninput="update(this)" placeholder="input" cols="70" rows="10" wrap="on"></textarea>
<h3>OUTPUT</h3>
<textarea id="outputText" placeholder="output" cols="70" rows="10" wrap="on" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I realized I had 2 lines of code in my electron app that made scripts useless. I deleted them and now every script works...   ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the textarea change event

```
document.querySelector("#inputText").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  document.querySelector("#outputText").textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

and when that event appears, change the output text's inner text

**BUT** the change will only appear after the textarea loses focus, so you could react to the keyup event instead, that will make it real-time :)

```
document.querySelector("#inputText").addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  document.querySelector("#outputText").textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

Or you can use your code, where you just swaped sides, forgot the keyword and you want the element's value, not the whole element

```
let str = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
let res = str.toUpperCase();
document.getElementById("outputText").textContent = res;
```

Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` as it's safe

and I use `let` instead of `var`, you should too, look it up

Answer (score 1):

Ok so for that you will first have to make some kind of button that will then trigger the script to run so I have done that in the following:

```
<h3>INPUT</h3>
    <textarea id="inputText" placeholder="input" cols="70" rows="10" wrap="on"></textarea>
    <button onclick="MakeUpper()">Enter</button>
<h3>OUTPUT</h3>
    <textarea id="outputText" placeholder="output" cols="70" rows="10" wrap="on" readonly></textarea>
```

Then for the script it shall be a normal function:

```
function MakeUpper() {
        var upperCase = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
        var upperCase = upperCase.toUpperCase();
        document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML = upperCase;
    }
```

Hope this solved your query also sorry for any bad code formatting as this is my first time answering a question on the website

Answer (score 0):

Your first assignment isn’t valid; the variable name (`str`) always goes on the left.

```
var str = document.getElementById("inputText").value
```

You also need `.value` to get the value of the input. More explicitly:

```
var inputTextarea = document.getElementById("inputText")
var str = inputTextarea.value
```

Similarly you need to set `.value`, not `.innerText`:

```
var outputTextarea = document.getElementById("outputText")
outputTextarea.value = str
```

This will run now, but your central problem (it doesn’t update when you type) persists, because your code just runs once when the page loads. So you copy the value of nothing, then your script stops. You need it to run again whenever the input changes, which looks like this:

```
var inputTextarea = document.getElementById("inputText")
var outputTextarea = document.getElementById("outputText")

function copyText () {
    var upper = inputTextarea.value.toUpperCase()
    outputTextarea.value = upper
}

inputTextarea.addEventListener('change', copyText)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your js you are trying to do a very bad thing. This operation is called assignment. You can assign a value to a variable, but you are trying to the opposite things.
You want to practice, but in order to do that you need to learn some programming theory first: Variables, operators, functions...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web that would be a good start. Don't skip anything.

Comment: Your pseudo js code looks horribly. I think this is the main reason why people down vote it.